# Scroll to an element and hover over it

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to make a loop to hover over elements but when I find elements by class name it also gives me elements that are out of or on borders of my viewport. I tried this code below where I perform an arbitrary number of scrolls and in each one I try to hover only on elements within **y=50** to **y=900** of my viewport:

```
numofscrolls=20
for iscrolls in range(1,numofscrolls):
ymin=0
targets=currentpage.find_elements_by_class_name('css-4rbku5')
for i in range(0,len(targets)):          
    if targets[i].location['y']<=900+ymin and targets[i].location['y']>=ymin+50:
       hoverchain=action_chains.ActionChains(browser)
       hovernow=hoverchain.move_to_element(targets[i])
       hovernow.perform()
       browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1500)")
       ymin=ymin+1500
```

But I still get error saying that the elements are outside my viewport

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: (206, 1476) is out of bounds of viewport width (939) and height (973)
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. in Python, any wrong tab can produce different types of results.

Comment: I'm sorry, first time to use stack overflow on my phone. Will fix it ASAP. Anyways, the if loop is inside the for loop. And I don't have indentation errors when I use it

Comment: Actually, your code should produce an error as there is no semi-column for the first `for loop` ( `:`), `Numofscrolls` used once with capital `N` and another time with smallcaps `n` ... `For loop` with capital `F` ... are you using microsoft word to write code ?

Comment: thanks, no. i just tried to simplify it when I was posting it here. I removed irrelevant lines. so these were just typos when I was posting. I corrected that now